# array containing key-value pair javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rally

So I have this "story" array:

```
 story[0]=[{"_ref":"/hierarchicalrequirement/15475417305","FormattedID":"US79832","Owner":"A","EstCP":0}]
 story[1]=[{"_ref":"/hierarchicalrequirement/15790056238","FormattedID":"US81776","Owner":"B","EstCP":0}]
 story[2]=[{"_ref":"/hierarchicalrequirement/15790059145","FormattedID":"US81777","Owner":"C","EstCP":7.5}]
```

How do I get the "FormattedID" key of story[2]? I tried:

```
1. story[2].get("FormattedID")
2. story[2].FormattedID
3. story[2]["FormattedID"]
4. story[2][FormattedID]
5. story[2].getCollection("FormattedID")
6. story[2].get(FormattedID)
```

None of these works. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `story[2][0]["FormattedID"];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`story[2]` is an array with just one entry. You access that entry via `[0]`. That object has the property, so:

```
story[2][0].FormattedID
```

...gives you the value.

This may be clearer with some linebreaks. Here's what you're assigning to `story[2]`:

```
story[2]= [ // <== Starts array
    {       // <== Starts object
        "_ref": "/hierarchicalrequirement/15790059145",
        "FormattedID": "US81777",
        "Owner": "C",
        "EstCP": 7.5
    }       // <== Ends object
];          // <== Ends array
```

So `story[2][0]` gives us the object:

```
{
    "_ref": "/hierarchicalrequirement/15790059145",
    "FormattedID": "US81777",
    "Owner": "C",
    "EstCP": 7.5
}
```

...which has the `FormattedID` property. You can access that using dot notation and a literal property name (`.FormattedID`), or using bracketed notation and a string property name (`["FormattedID"]`).

Comment: Oh, I see, each story[i] is an array on its own. Sorry to have missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets when you are creating your story objects. Then you can get to it as you expect.

Example:

```
 story[0]={"_ref":"/hierarchicalrequirement/15475417305","FormattedID":"US79832","Owner":"A","EstCP":0}

story[0].FormattedID
```

With the brackets you are actually creating an array with one item at each spot in your main array.

Comment: Rick, that was a representation of the pre-defined array I was looking at. I did not define it that way.